# Angular.js and Raphael.js/Snap.svg - binding directive event handlers to Raphael.js-generated SVG content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I'm using Snap.svg from within an Angular.js directive to generate SVG content and am admittedly at this point contemplating scrapping Snap.svg altogether and just writing regular ol' XML-style SVGs. I figure that, before I throw in the towel on Snap.svg, I should at least ask whether it's possible to, using Angular, bind event handlers to the HTML Snap.svg generates. So far, I see no clear way to associate the Snap-generated HTML with the element parameter in an Angular directive. Also, I see no way to add directives directly to the markup Snap.svg generates. Trying to get the two to play nicely together feels . . . hacky.

Is there something I'm missing here? As you can see below, I am explicitly setting the element variable to the output of Snap.svg (I'm pretty sure this is incorrect, but, having first tried to allow the element variable to map to the actual HTML element to which the variable is associated by default, I figured I'd try something different.)

```
BoothManager.directive("booth", ["$document", "BoothShapeConstants", function ($document, BoothShapeConstants) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
          booth: "=info"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var s = Snap("#svg");

            var bigCircle  =  s.circle (20, 20, BoothShapeConstants.RADIUS).attr({
                fill: BoothShapeConstants.COLOR_FILL,
                stroke: BoothShapeConstants.COLOR_BORDER,
                strokeWidth: BoothShapeConstants.STROKE_WIDTH
            });


            bigCircle.drag(moveElement);


            function moveElement (dx, dy, posx, posy) {
                this.attr({
                cx: posx,
                cy: posy
            });
        };

        console.log(element);

        element.on("mousedown", function (event) {
            console.log(scope.booth.id); 
        });

        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS how to bind data with SVG widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698791/angularjs-how-to-bind-data-with-svg-widget)

Comment: @Paul: That question suggests using a directive to bind data; here, they are already using a directive and binding data; they are asking not how to bind data, but how to bind ***events***. Therefore, this is not a duplicate.